# AWS step functions - Transform {AWS::AccountId}::StepFunctionsYamlTransform failed without an error message

Tags: amazon-web-services, yaml, aws-cloudformation, aws-step-functions

I am writing a cloudformation template for creating an **aws step function** and **statemachine**. Following is the part of my template which is causing the error

```
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: 2010-09-09
Transform:
- StepFunctionsYamlTransform

StepFunctionsStateMachine:
  Type: AWS::StepFunctions::StateMachine
  Properties:
    StateMachineName: MyStack
    RoleArn: !GetAtt StateMachineRole.Arn
    DefinitionStringYaml: !Sub
    - |
      Comment: My-Stack-workflow
      StartAt: LambdaToStart
      TimeoutSeconds: 43200
      States:
        LambdaToStart:
          Type: Task
          Resource: "${LambdaToStartArn}"
          Next: WaitToWriteInS3
        WaitToWriteInS3:
          Type: Wait
          Seconds: 5
          Next: Batch_Job_1
        Batch_Job_1:
          Type: Task
          Next: LambdaForTriggerEmrJob
          Resource: arn:aws:states:::batch:submitJob.sync
          Parameters:
            JobName: "${BatchJob1}"
            JobDefinition: "${BatchJob1DefinitionArn}"
            JobQueue: arn:aws:batch:${AWS::Region}:${AWS::AccountId}:job-queue/${QueueName}
        LambdaForTriggerEmrJob:
          Type: Task
          Resource: "${LambdaForEmrArn}"
          Next: WaitFoEmrState
        WaitFoEmrState:
          Type: Wait
          Seconds: 90
          Next: CheckEmrState
        CheckEmrState:
          Type: Task
          Resource: "${ClusterStateCheckArn}"
          InputPath: "$.input.cluster"  # Values coming from lambda
          ResultPath: "$.input.cluster"  # Values coming from lambda
          Retry: *LambdaRetryConfig
          Next: IsClusterRunning
        IsClusterRunning:
          Type: Choice
          Default: WaitFoEmrState
          Choices:
          - Variable: "$.input.cluster.state"
            StringEquals: FAILED
            Next: StateMachineFailure
          - Variable: "$.input.cluster.state" # Values coming from lambda
            StringEquals: SUCCEEDED
            Next: FinalBatchJob
        StateMachineFailure:
          Type: Fail
        FinalBatchJob:
          Type: Task
          Resource: arn:aws:states:::batch:submitJob.sync
          Parameters:
            JobName: "${FinalBatch}"
            JobDefinition: "${FinalBatchDefinitionArn}"
            JobQueue: arn:aws:batch:${AWS::Region}:${AWS::AccountId}:job-queue/${QueueName
          End: true
    - LambdaToStartArn: !GetAtt LambdaToStart.Arn
      LambdaForEmrArn: !GetAtt LambdaForEmr.Arn
      BatchJob1DefinitionArn: !Ref BatchJob1Definition
      FinalBatchDefinitionArn: !Ref FinalBatchDefinition
      BatchJob1: !Sub ${AWS::StackName}-batch-1
      FinalBatch: !Sub ${AWS::StackName}-final-batch
      ClusterStateCheckArn: !Sub arn:aws:lambda:${AWS::Region}:${AWS::AccountId}:function:cluster-state
```

It returns the following error

```
Failed to create the changeset: Waiter ChangeSetCreateComplete failed:
Waiter encountered a terminal failure state Status: FAILED. Reason: 
Transform {AWS::AccountId}::StepFunctionsYamlTransform failed without an 
error message.
```

Can anyone help in recognising the solution to this? I can't debug a lot since it fails without an error message. TIA

Comment: And `StepFunctionsYamlTransform` is exactly what?

Comment: Its exactly for transforming the Json syntax to Yaml. In cloudformation some configurations require json object so this transformation provides consistency in the template

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AWS cloudformation errors are sometimes quite wierd and its difficult to debug them. But I found the error. It was 9th line `JobQueue: arn:aws:batch:${AWS::Region}:${AWS::AccountId}:job-queue/${QueueName` and one can easily see that I missed `}` at the end. So it was a syntax error